# Setting DateTime format in Delphi with Firedac compatible with BDE Application

Tags: delphi, firebird, datetime-format, firedac, bde

I am migrating my application from Delphi2007 and BDE to Delphi 10.4 and Firedac. The new application is in testing, the old app is still there for backup, in case the new application fails.

So, I have 2 applications talking to the same database, one with Firedac, the other with BDE.

The following happens:

As soon as Firedac saves a DateTime field (date + time), that record can no longer be changed in the BDE application. (I use TQuery->DatasetProvide->TClientDataset, updatemode WhereAll, no persistent fields in the TQuery)

Probably, Firedac stores the time-part in a format that confuses the BDE/Datasetprovider.

Is it possible to make Firedac store time in a format the BDE does understand?

I know, the solution *could* be : adding persistent fields (> 100 tables), and setting the providerflag to pfInkey for all primary keys, and adding datasetproviders with updatemode "whereKeyOnly", but I do not want to change that much and spend so much time on the (very big) old (and soon to be deprecated) application that uses BDE.

I tried mappingrules in Firedac. I added 2 rules:

DateTimeStamp-> DateTime, DateTime -> DateTime.

For both rules I tested with values of *PrecMax* of 4,6,8. I thought maybe this way the time-value is stored with less precision, but this had no effect. Maybe some other value or mapping?

ADDITION

Editing the field with a dbExpress TSQLCOnnection instead of BDE works.
The default persistent field with TQuery  is TDateTime, with dbExpress: TsqlTimeStamp. It seems like the "TDateTime" field is incompattible with values stored as a timestamp. The error is raized when apllying updates. Fetching the data is no problem.

Comment: You need to be certain about this. Are the datetimes stored in a varchar/string field in the tables? How is the data different when written by BDE vs written by FireDac? Are you sure this is really your problem? Maybe it's something else.

Comment: Yes, I am 99% sure. I spent 3 days testing and isolating the problem... 
The fields are of the type DATE in a Firebird Database. I can see no difference in the values that are stored by Firedac or BDE, but I am not sure I am looking at the 'raw' data ...

Comment: If the field is `DATE`, then there is no different format, there is only one way to store them. Please provide a [mre], relevant DDL, errors, and specify whether your database is dialect 1 (where `DATE` is actually a `TIMESTAMP`), or dialect 3 (where `DATE` is really only a date).

Comment: The field is DATE, dialect 1. I will try to make an example.

Comment: What is the best way to share my minimal reproducible example? Upload a zip-file, or share the complete source code in my question ?